after recent upgrade to 24.04 noble acess to local web pages returned a 504 (out of service)
fwiw:
i had changed apache2's user and group to httpd. after the upgrade to noble, web access returned 503s.
turns out, part of this upgrade was also php from 8.1 to 8.3.
i had previously changed the apache user:group to httpd, and the php-fpm socket owner:group default to httpd:httpd.
forgot about that.
the change was to the 2 sets of owner:group entries in /etc/php/php8.3/pool.d/www.conf.
i just didn't like how www-data looked.
O.

Lots of handwaving, little detail. Which commands did you use? What results? What did you intend? To make ls output myweb instead of www-data? To make your web development experience easier? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
